# D3 not setting its own height and cutting off last data item

Tags: d3.js

Why does my svg container gets set to a height of 150 on its own. I have a csv with 4 rows of data but the last one does not get shown in the browser. I am not setting the svg container to a height. I am trying to use ordinal scale for the y vertical placement of the bar graphs. When viewing in elements in chrome dev tools I see the last row but it is at 153 and the svg is set to 150. Why does it get set to 150 and how do I show all the items in the csv?

```
<body>
    <svg id="container"></svg>
</body>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let container = d3.select("#container");
        d3.csv("weight-height.csv").then(showData); 

        function write(text) {
            container.append("div").text(text);
        }

        function showData(clients) {

            let max = d3.max(clients, d => d.Weight);
            let widthScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0, max])
                .range([0, 300]);

            let positionScale  = d3.scaleBand()
                .domain(clients.map(d => d.Name))
                .range([0, 200])
                .padding(0.3);

            let join = container
                .selectAll("rect")
                .data(clients);

            join.enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("fill", "blue")
                .attr("width", d => widthScale(d.Weight))
                .attr("height", positionScale.bandwidth())
                .attr("y", d => positionScale(d.Name));

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: 300×150 pixels is the default size for an SVG embedded into HTML. If you need other dimensions you'll have to set them yourself. Amelia Bellamy-Royds wrote an excellent post on [How to Scale SVG](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/).

Comment: Thank you altcoumulus! Thank for the link as well. What I had read before did not mention the default size.